# Issues with using stateful in StackedRNN cells

Tags: python, tensorflow, rnn

I am having issues with using the 'stateful' feature when building stacked RNN using LSTMCell object. I am following the instructions on tensorflow on how to set 'stateful = True' by passing the 'batch_shape' to the input layer and the 'batch_input_shape' to the first cell, and also tried to set it in the second cell but it still does not work; tried various combinations but nothing works. The code only works with one cell but not with more than one. I am not sure what I am missing.

The problem I am working on is Sentiment Analysis. 292 is the sequence length I am passing to predict if the sentiment is 1 or 0.

I realize I could use the Sequential model of Keras but I would like to learn the finer features of tensorflow.

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf.reset_default_graph()

batch_size = 10
embed_size = 5
dropout = 0.5
n_unique_words = 102966
ntimesteps = 292


x = tf.placeholder(dtype = tf.int32, shape = (batch_size, ntimesteps), name='tf_x')
print(x)

y = tf.placeholder(dtype = tf.float32, shape = (batch_size), name = 'tf_y')
print(y)

embed_variable = tf.get_variable(name = 'embedding', shape = [n_unique_words, embed_size], initializer=tf.glorot_uniform_initializer)
print(embed_variable)

embed_x = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embed_variable, x, name = 'embedded_x')
print(embed_x)

cell1 = tf.keras.layers.LSTMCell(units = 256, batch_input_shape = (10,292,5), dtype = tf.float32)#, dropout=dropout, name = 'lstm1')
print(cell1)


cell2 = tf.keras.layers.LSTMCell(units = 512, batch_input_shape = (10,292,5), dtype = tf.float32)#, name='lstm2', recurrent_dropout=0.5) 
print(cell2)


rnn_input = tf.keras.Input(batch_shape = (batch_size, 292, 5), dtype = tf.float32) #shape = (batch_size, 292))#
rnn_object = tf.keras.layers.RNN(cell = [cell1, cell2], batch_size = 10, return_sequences = True, \
                                 return_state = True, stateful = True, dtype = tf.float32)(rnn_input)


print(rnn_object)
```

Output:

````
Tensor("tf_x:0", shape=(10, 292), dtype=int32)
Tensor("tf_y:0", shape=(10,), dtype=float32)
<tf.Variable 'embedding:0' shape=(102966, 5) dtype=float32_ref>
Tensor("embedded_x/Identity:0", shape=(10, 292, 5), dtype=float32)
<tensorflow.python.keras.layers.recurrent.LSTMCell object at 0x7fd8088a3b38>
<tensorflow.python.keras.layers.recurrent.LSTMCell object at 0x7fd8088a3fd0>
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-641a99b06a11> in <module>
     32 rnn_input = tf.keras.Input(batch_shape = (batch_size, 292, 5), dtype = tf.float32) #shape = (batch_size, 292))#
     33 rnn_object = tf.keras.layers.RNN(cell = [cell1, cell2], batch_size = 10, return_sequences = True, \
---> 34                                  return_state = True, stateful = True, dtype = tf.float32)(rnn_input)
     35 
     36 

~/anaconda3/envs/condapy36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/recurrent.py in __call__(self, inputs, initial_state, constants, **kwargs)
    699 
    700     if initial_state is None and constants is None:
--> 701       return super(RNN, self).__call__(inputs, **kwargs)
    702 
    703     # If any of `initial_state` or `constants` are specified and are Keras

~/anaconda3/envs/condapy36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py in __call__(self, inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    536       if not self.built:
    537         # Build layer if applicable (if the `build` method has been overridden).
--> 538         self._maybe_build(inputs)
    539         # We must set self.built since user defined build functions are not
    540         # constrained to set self.built.

~/anaconda3/envs/condapy36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py in _maybe_build(self, inputs)
   1601     # Only call `build` if the user has manually overridden the build method.
   1602     if not hasattr(self.build, '_is_default'):
-> 1603       self.build(input_shapes)
   1604 
   1605   def __setattr__(self, name, value):

~/anaconda3/envs/condapy36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/recurrent.py in build(self, input_shape)
    634       ]
    635     if self.stateful:
--> 636       self.reset_states()
    637     self.built = True
    638 

~/anaconda3/envs/condapy36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/recurrent.py in reset_states(self, states)
    904           K.set_value(state,
    905                       np.zeros([batch_size] +
--> 906                                tensor_shape.as_shape(dim).as_list()))
    907       else:
    908         K.set_value(self.states[0], np.zeros(

~/anaconda3/envs/condapy36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py in set_value(x, value)
   2831           (of the same shape).
   2832   """
-> 2833   value = np.asarray(value, dtype=dtype(x))
   2834   if ops.executing_eagerly_outside_functions():
   2835     x.assign(value)

~/anaconda3/envs/condapy36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py in dtype(x)
   1013   ```
   1014   """
-> 1015   return x.dtype.base_dtype.name
   1016 
   1017 

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'dtype'
````

Comment: Welcome to the site! All LSTMs are stateful by definition, you cannot turn it off. Variable `stateful = True` is [something different](https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/), turn it False. And I don't think removing the `stateful` make this error go away, you have a problem with your input, see [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47315445/5341713).

Comment: Yes, that is for LSTM layer. But I am building an RNN using LSTMCell and there is no option for setting stateful in LSTMCell. Its only in the RNN layer where that option is. As mentioned in my issue, I followed the instructions in the tf documentation to set stateful but nothing worked - I dont know if I have missed something. Also, with stateful = False, when I tried to set the states of the next batch using rnn.reset_states(states = [from previous batch]) I get the error 'AttributeError: Layer must be stateful.'